# MySQL Preference Pane completely erased my entire /usr/local directory

Tags: mysql, macos

During a one-click uninstall of MySQL via the MySQL preference pane in macOS Mojave, I watched in horror as, one by one, the contents—all directories and files—of my `usr/local` directory disappeared forever. This include Homebrew and all of my brew installations/caskets.

In the MySQL Preference Pane, all of the directory settings pointed to subdirectories of `usr/local/mysql/...`, which was not at all to be found prior to the uninstallation, so I figured nothing outside of it would be deleted, because there was nothing to delete. **I had no idea the entire contents of my `usr/local` directory would be permanently trashed.**

Question: Is this cause for concern, or is this the expected behavior of MySQL uninstallation via the macOS MySQL Preference Pane?

Comment: This sounds frightening, but my guess would be that MySQL, for whatever reason, is viewing `usr/local` as its data or config directory.  So, the actual problem might have been with your previous MySQL installation, not the uninstallation.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You may be entirely correct. But if so, then it is utterly disastrous design that the "Uninstall" command from the PreferencePane would touch anything aside from those folders listed explicitly one tab over in the same PreferencePane.

Please educate me if I am missing something about how MySQL installations work. Perhaps the official MySQL pane shouldn't be taking the blame?

Comment: This is something you need address to the MySql team since it might be a really bad bug, you might also try https://dba.stackexchange.com/ but it is not a programming issue so stackoverflow is not the place for this question

Comment: @JoakimDanielson You're right. Muscle memory. I'll post over at dba.stackexchange.com.